# Gradient of $L=\|Y - X\|_F^2 + \sum_i^I u_i ( \| A_i X_i \|_2^2 - \alpha_i ) + \sum_k^K v_k ( {\rm tr}( (X^* B_k X^T)) - \beta_k)$ w.r.t. $X$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am not sure how to start with computing the gradient $\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}$ of the following function:

\begin{align}
L = \| Y - X \|_F^2 + \sum_i^I  u_i \left(  \| A_i X_i \|_2^2 - \alpha_i \right)  + \sum_k^K  v_k \left( {\rm tr} \left( (X^* B_k X^T) \right) - \beta_k \right)
\end{align} 
where

- $Y \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, i.e., complex-valued matrix,
- $X \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$,
- $X^*$ denotes complex conjugate only, $X^T$ corresponds to transpose of the matrix $X$,
- $X_i \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times 1}$ denotes $i$th column vector of $X$ matrix,
- $A_i \in \mathbb{C}^{p \times m}$ is given,
- $B_k \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is given,
- $u_i, \alpha_i, v_k, \beta_k \in \mathbb{R}$ are given.

---

I thought if I could write the second part in matrix form, then probably I can move forward and try to compute the gradient. But I fail to do that. 
Your suggestions and help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the difficult part? Is the term with  $X_i$ or the second sum?

Comment: Yes, the second sum including the $X_i$ vectors of a matrix $X$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work on it one piece at a time.

The first piece
$$\eqalign{K &= \|X-Y\|_F^2 = (X-Y)^*:(X-Y) \cr dK &= (X-Y)^*:dX}$$
The second piece.
$$\eqalign{M &=\|AXe\|_F^2 =(AXe)^*:(AXe)\cr dM &=(AXe)^*:A\,dX\,e =A^TA^*X^*ee^T:dX}$$
And the third.
$$\eqalign{
N &={\rm Tr}(X^*BX^T) =X^*B:X\cr dN &=X^*B:dX}$$
Now put it all together, with various summation coefficients (omit the constant terms).
$$\eqalign{
L &= K + \sum_iu_iM_i + \sum_kv_kN_k \cr
dL &= \Big((X-Y)^* + \sum_iu_iA_i^TA_i^*X^*e_ie_i^T + \sum_kv_kX^*B_k\Big):dX \cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}
 &= X^*-Y^* + \sum_iu_iA_i^TA_i^*X^*e_ie_i^T + \sum_kv_kX^*B_k \cr\cr
}$$
In the above derivation, a colon denotes the double-dot product
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Also $X^*$ is treated as being independent of $X$ under differentiation, also known as Wirtinger derivatives or the ${\mathbb {CR}-}$calculus.

And $e_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector for ${\mathbb R}^{n}$

Comment: Thank you greg. You might be correct. But I am so sorry and I am still confused with the second piece, particularly. $X_i$ is an $i$th column vector of matrix $X$. I intend to take the gradient with respect to $X$ matrix. So, how can $dM_i = A_i^T A_i^* X^* : dX$? Should it not be $dM_i = A_i^T A_i^* X_i^* : dX_i$? If yes, then how to arrange $dX_i$ as $dX$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the subscript on $X_i$. The answer has been updated.

Comment: Awesome, greg! This is a nice trick. Thank you so much.